# Showing that a finite abelian group of exponent $n$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^r$ for some $r$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism

This is a remark of [Milne's *Fields and Galois Theory*](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/FT.pdf) on page 72.

This is the first time I have seen the term *exponent* in group theory. Though the definitions seem to be easy and I was able to easily understand the [results regarding the exponent on Groupprops](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Exponent_of_a_group) with their proofs, I do not see how I can convince me why this result is true.

Let $G$ be a finite and abelian group with exponent $n$.

If $G$ is finite, then $n = {\operatorname{lcm}}_{\substack g \in G}(ord(g))$. I guess that I need to put the fact that $G$ is abelian but I don't know where this is useful.

Could you please explain this result to me?

Comment: There are several potential answers, depending on how much group theory you are supposed to know and can use.  If you know the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups (or finitely generated ones), then this is easy.  But one can get a bit more primitive by somewhat algorithmically writing $G$ as a direct product of cyclic groups if you don't.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy: I dealt with the fundamental theorem of finitely generated groups - at least I am able to sketch its proof if it is in front of me. I remembered that it has something to do with the Smith normal form but I never worked explicit examples. So maybe an algorithmic approach is still nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $G$ is finite abelian, the fundamental structure theorem days that $G\simeq \mathbb{Z}/d_1\mathbb{Z}\times\cdots \times \mathbb{Z}/d_r\mathbb{Z}$ , where $r\geq 0$ and $2\leq d_1\mid d_2\cdots\mid d_r$.

It is easy to check that $\exp(G)=d_r$. Hence your assumption translates to $d_r=n$.
Now $d_i\mid d_r=n$, so writing $n=d_i m_i$, we have that $\bar{m}_i\in\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ has order $d_i$, so $\langle \bar{m}_i\rangle\simeq \mathbb{Z}/d_i\mathbb{Z}$.
Hence $G$ is isomorphic to $\langle \bar{m}_1\rangle\times\cdots \times \langle \bar{m}_r\rangle$, which is the desired subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^r$.